# Python multiprocessing share large data through Queue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I would like to put output data into a queue in a multiprocessing computation. It seems that when the size of the return is too large, the program got stuck. To illustrate the problem, here is a minimal codes. Anyone can help to make this work?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import numpy as np

def foo(q, qid):
    x = np.random.randint(0,5,7)
    y = np.random.random(100*10*10).reshape(100,10,10)
    q.put([qid,x,y])

def main():
    processes = []
    q = Queue()

    for qid in range(5):
        p = Process(target=foo, args=(q, qid))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    for qid in range(5):
        [_, x, y] = q.get()
        print(x)
        print(y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean "stuck"?   No error message?  Locked up?  Or was it just taking a long time?   Start with smaller data to ensure your program works as expected and slowly increase the data size.

Comment: Smaller data works well. For the example above, it just stuck without error messages. The debugger can run to q.put()

Comment: There may be good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552716/multiprocessing-queue-full#34035902)
Perhaps you can go somewhat larger by giving each process its own queue, but as the above link will tell you, there's underlying implementation issues for queue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deadlock with big object in multiprocessing.Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196165/deadlock-with-big-object-in-multiprocessing-queue)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one solution is as below to switch the `join` and `get`. By default, the `get` method blocks.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import numpy as np

def foo(q, qid):
    x = np.random.randint(0,5,7)
    y = np.random.random(100*10*10).reshape(100,10,10)
    q.put([qid,x,y])

def main():
    processes = []
    q = Queue()

    for qid in range(5):
        p = Process(target=foo, args=(q, qid))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for qid in range(5):
        [_, x, y] = q.get()
        print(x)
        print(y)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```